# What kind of plastic is (really) safe to store vegetable oil?

Tags: organic-chemistry, plastics, lipids

Storing colza or olive oil in a plastic bottle might be risky since the oil can leach out phthalates and BPA (and others molecules?).

Some manufacturers sell "phthalates and BPA free bottles", but are they safe to store oil?

What kind of plastic would you use to store oil?

Comment: I would use amber glass.

Comment: @andselisk I need something light and unbreakable (that would fit in a backpack)

Comment: Glass would be better than any plastic, but if you need a lightweight container for a short period of time, I suspect that any food-grade plastic is going to be acceptable. Although I don't see the problem with glass: my colleague used to carry a couple of 1 L lass bottles with some lemonade each day to the university in his backpack without any issues.

Comment: @andselisk try to walk few thousand kilometers with a glass bottle on your backpack, you'll start to love plastic, very much. (it's robust and above all, super light)

Comment: How long do you need to store the oil?  For long-term storage, all plastics will leach, in which case you might need to sacrifice some weight and consider a stainless steel water bottle.

Comment: @theorist, "all plastics will leach". Oh that's bad new. But how long is "long-term storage"?

Comment: A stainless steel water bottle is not much heavier than plastic, especially when full

Comment: I just use the plastic bottle the olive oil came in from the store. For backpacking you buy the tiny little bottle and get a good easy-pour dripless spout good for pouring olive oil with the bottle. Remember to store in a ziploc bag since you really don't want olive oil all over everything should the lid fail.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to tell us exactly how you will be using this. E.g. : "I want to carry 4 oz. of olive oil, for cooking purposes, on weekend backpacking trips." Or: "I'm hauling supplies, on foot, to my cabin that's a 2-day hike into the backcountry. On my next trip I'd like to leave a quart of olive oil there."  See also this report from the UC Davis Olive Oil Center: https://1.oliveoiltimes.com/library/olive-oil-packaging.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned, I would suggest that high-density poly ethylene (HDPE) or poly propylene (PP) to be better options. HDPE is a heavy duty plastic resistant to most chemicals and physical deformation- it is often used for household products including bleach, detergent etc, but is also commonly used for milk bottles and the like.

Comment: "There is evidence indicating that phthalates can leach from PET and HDPE bottles into their contents" https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/283768

Comment: But, some manufacturer sell oil (or milk, which contains lipids) in plastic bottles which could mean either that they are completely safe, or they are safe for some time, or they leach out chemicals but they (most manufacturers/consumers) don't care.

Comment: I appreciate the reference. Most oil products are triglycerides and are non-acidic, so I would question the relevance, however, I will point to the conclusion in that paper which still supports the idea that HDPE is safe: "... PET- and HDPE- bottled liquids do not represent a relevant ingestion source of phthalate... and therefore, the concentrations of phthalates observed in them are not a matter of concern from the standpoint of adverse health effects".

Comment: So I am confused as to why would you reference an unreliable paper that you agree isn't relevant- but I suppose this thread is moving away from the question, so I will leave it at that.